I keep on getting GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/room/f5428fc5 404 (Not Found):
Im making a Next.js and Django full stack app with Spotify api, and Im having trouble fetching the get-room api, when ever I click on the button to create a room in the create.js page the room is created and a unique code is generated but the room is not found. can anyone help me?:
from create.js page
const handleRoomButtonPressed = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        votes_to_skip: votesToSkip,
        guest_can_pause: guestCanPause,
      }),
    };
    fetch("/api/create-room", requestOptions) // Update the URL path
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => router.push("/room/" + data.code))
      .catch((error) => setErrorMsg("Error creating room..."));
  };

const renderCreateButtons = () => {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-2">
        <button
          className=" bg-spotifyGreen text-white rounded-lg px-4 py-2 mb-2 hover:bg-spotifyLight "
          onClick={handleRoomButtonPressed}
        >
          Create A Room
        </button>
        <button
          className="bg-red-500 text-white rounded-lg px-4 py-2 hover:bg-red-400"
          onClick={() => router.push("/")}
        >
          <ArrowBackIcon /> Back
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };


from the room.js page:
const [roomDetails, setRoomDetails] = useState({
    votesToSkip: 2,
    guestCanPause: false,
    isHost: false,
    spotifyAuthenticated: false,
    song: {},
  });

 const { roomCode } = router.query; 

  const getRoomDetails = () => {
    fetch("/api/get-room" + "?code=" + roomCode)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          leaveRoomCallback();
          navigate("/");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setRoomDetails({
          votesToSkip: data.votes_to_skip,
          guestCanPause: data.guest_can_pause,
          isHost: data.is_host,
        });
        if (data.is_host) {
          authenticateSpotify();
        }
      });
  };

from api/urls:
from django.urls import path
from .views import RoomView, CreateRoomView, GetRoom, JoinRoom, UserInRoom, LeaveRoom, UpdateRoom

urlpatterns = [
    path('room', RoomView.as_view()),
    path('create-room', CreateRoomView.as_view()), 
    path('get-room', GetRoom.as_view()),
    path('join-room', JoinRoom.as_view()),
    path('user-in-room', UserInRoom.as_view()),
    path('leave-room', LeaveRoom.as_view()),
    path('update-room', UpdateRoom.as_view())
]

from api/views:
class GetRoom(APIView):
serializer_class = RoomSerializer
lookup_url_kwarg = 'code'

def get(self, request, format=None):
code = request.GET.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
if code is not None:
room = Room.objects.filter(code=code).first()
if room is not None:
data = RoomSerializer(room).data
data['is_host'] = self.request.session.session_key == room.host
return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
return Response({'Room Not Found': 'Invalid Room Code.'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
return Response({'Bad Request': 'Code parameter not found in request'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class CreateRoomView(APIView):
serializer_class = CreateRoomSerializer

def post(self, request, format=None):
if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
self.request.session.create()

serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
guest_can_pause = serializer.data.get('guest_can_pause')
votes_to_skip = serializer.data.get('votes_to_skip')
host = self.request.session.session_key

code = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]  

room = Room(host=host, guest_can_pause=guest_can_pause, votes_to_skip=votes_to_skip, code=code)
room.save()
self.request.session['room_code'] = room.code
return Response(RoomSerializer(room).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid data...'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

from api/models.py:
from django.db import models
import string 
import random

def generate_unique_code():
    length = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))
        if Room.objects.filter(code=code).count() == 0:
            break

        return code


# Create your models here.
    
class Room(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="", unique=True)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    guest_can_pause = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    votes_to_skip = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  

from frontend/urls:
from django.urls import path
from .views import RoomView, CreateRoomView, GetRoom, JoinRoom, UserInRoom, LeaveRoom, UpdateRoom

urlpatterns = [
    path('room', RoomView.as_view()),
    path('create-room', CreateRoomView.as_view()), 
    path('get-room', GetRoom.as_view()),
    path('join-room', JoinRoom.as_view()),
    path('user-in-room', UserInRoom.as_view()),
    path('leave-room', LeaveRoom.as_view()),
    path('update-room', UpdateRoom.as_view())
]

Ive tried changing the paths on the fetch and still havent gotten any changes.

From the error in your title it seems you get the 404 for your frontend, i.e. your frontend does not have any URL like that, can you show where you've setup the URLs for your frontend?

Yes, here is the repo. https://github.com/Amirlasalle/next_house_party

No, all of the code / explanation required to understand your question needs to be in the question body itself. An external URL is not acceptable for a [mre].
